# Win: Remove duplicate lines in huge txt file

Tags: windows-7, duplicate

I need to remove duplicate lines from a huge txt. The file is about 150 mb big. When I try PSPad, I get memory error (despite I have 8 GB RAM).

Have you any idea or advice how to remove these duplicates?

Comment: This is not an answer - due to "Win:" in the subject/title - but anyway: Goto `www.cygwin.com` and download the basic install (i.e. you get a very basic "bash" in a terminal - given that you do NOT ADD anything). Then open a terminal, cd to where you have the file and type `sort THEFILE.txt | uniq -ui >UNIQUE.txt` ... type `uniq --help | less` and `sort --help | less` for short info on how these two commands work.

Answer (score 2):

[Gawk: pattern scanning and processing language](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)
Download->Binaries->Zip

Copy "awk.exe" (gawk-3.1.6-1-bin\bin\awk.exe) to your directory. Create bat file:

```
awk "!x[$0]++" huge.txt>output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download $Notepad++ and use the TextFX plugin. Install Text FX by going to `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Available tab -> TextFX -> Install`. After you have it installed, there will be a new menu called `TextFX` Select the portion of your document with duplicated (or just select the whole document). Go to `TextFX  -> TextFX Tools` , select `+Sort outputs only UNIQUE...` and either `sort lines case sensitive` or `sort lines case insensitive`.